# Pinia getter does not update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I have following code

```
<script lang="ts">
import { RouterView } from "vue-router";
import defaultLayout from "@/layouts/default.vue";
import dashboardLayout from "@/layouts/dashboard.vue";
import { useDefaultStore } from "@/stores/default";
import "./index.css";
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    let { getLayout } = useDefaultStore();

    return { getLayout };
  },
  components: { defaultLayout, dashboardLayout },
});
</script>

<template>
  {{ getLayout }}
  <component :is="getLayout">
    <RouterView />
  </component>
</template>
```

When i got to `/dashboard` my state gets updated but the getter does not for some reason, why is that?

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useDefaultStore } from "@/stores/default";
let { getUserData, SET_LAYOUT, getLayout } = useDefaultStore();
SET_LAYOUT("dashboardLayout");
</script>
```

Here my store:

```
actions: {
    SET_LAYOUT(layout: any) {
      console.log("setting layout");
      console.log(layout);
      this.layout = layout;
    },
}
```

I literally can see the changes inside the console but they does not get applied on the UI

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have found it out.

You cannot destructure your store, it loses its reactivity

```
let { getLayout } = useDefaultStore();
```

So i changed it to

```
let store = useDefaultStore();
```

and used `store.getLayout` and it works!

Comment: Thanks! I tripped up on this same issue! I assumed to maintain reactivity only the state needed storeToRefs to when destructuring the store. However, both state and getters need it. Actions work fine without it though.

Comment: This is one way to handle it. Another way is pointed out by Estus Flask's comment that lets you use destructuring while maintaining reactivity

Answer (score 12):

This is covered by the documentation, this is the case for [`storeToRefs` helper](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#using-the-store):

```
const { getLayout } = storeToRefs(useDefaultStore());
```