# Pinia getter not returning updated value

Tags: typescript, vue.js, pinia

I'm using Pinia with Vue.  My store looks like this:

```
interface LoginStore {
  token?: string;
}

export const useLoginStore = defineStore('login', {
  state: () => ({} as LoginStore),
  actions: {
    async login(email: string, password: string): Promise<boolean> {
      try {
        const result = await api.post('/api/user/login', { email, password });
        this.token = result.data.data.token;
        return true;
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Login Error', err);
        return false;
      }
    },
  },
  getters: {
    isLoggedIn: (state) => {
      return state.token != null;
    }
  }
});
```

When I call `loginStore.login()` I can see the request succeeds, but the `isLoggedIn`  getter continues to return false.

I'm using `storeToRefs` for the access, so it's not that I haven't remembered to restructure the store ([this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323650/pinia-getter-does-not-update)).

```
const { isLoggedIn } = storeToRefs(useLoginStore());
```

Why would `isLoggedIn` continue to be `false` after `state.token` is set?

Answer (score 1):

Properties with type `undefined` need to be specified in the initial state of the store.  Seems counterintuitive, but if you initialize it by leaving those out:

```
state: () => ({} as LoginStore),
```

Then the getter won't work.  If you initialize them with `undefined`, the getter will work.

```
state: () => ({
  token: undefined,
} as LoginStore),
```

Comment: It's a good practice to use null for such cases, this allows to clearly distinguish undefined and uninitialized values