# Pinia getter not reactive

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

I have a Pinia store, from which I want to return a calculated value based on the current state. For some reason, the getter is not reactive in the component using the store.

#### myStore.js

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';

export const useMyStore = defineStore('myStore', () => {
  const someArray = ref([]);

  /* Initialize the state from outside the store */

  const getterOne = computed(() => {
    return someArray;  // This works
  });

  const getterTwo = computed(() => {
    return someArray.value.length;  // This is not reactive
  });
});
```

#### myComponent

```
import { useMyStore } from 'stores/myStore';
const myStore = useMyStore();

// This is reactive and updates with state changes
const foo = myStore.getterOne;

// This is not reactive and doesn't update. It only updates when reloading the component after the state has changed.
const bar = myStore.getterTwo;
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this the expected behavior of Pinia or should the getter be reactive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pinia getter does not update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323650/pinia-getter-does-not-update)

Comment: No sorry, I already had a look at that question before asking. It doesn't answer the question why `getterOne` is reactive but `getterTwo` isn't.

Comment: 'getterOne' returns a ref, and refs are reactive. `getterTwo` returns a number, numbers are not reactive. To access the value in a reactive way, you have to use `storeToRefs` or consistently access it through the store.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I understand it now. What do you mean by consistently accessing it through the store?

Comment: If you always write `myStore.getterTwo`, it will work too. `myStore.getterTwo` is reactive. But it is the access through the store that makes it reactive. Assigning the value (directly or by destructuring) will give you a simple (non-reactive) number.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you very much. Now I understand Pinia a little bit better.

Answer (score 0):

try to apply the following, and it should work.

```
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';

const myStore = useMyStore();
const { bar } = storeToRefs(myStore);
```

Now your getter is reactive.